# No errors in console after registering a library with Silex

Tags: php, silex

I tryed to add FormServiceProvider library to my bootstrap.
I had to download it because it wasn't in "light" Silex Framework version.

So I put it in my library
(Here's the structure)

```
Sources
   --- private
      --- application
         --- controllers
         bootstrap.php
      --- data
      --- libraries
         --- Silex
            --- Provider
                   FormServiceProvider.php
                   SessionServiceProvider.php
                   ...
            silex.phar
         --- Swift
         --- Symfony
         --- ...
```

(I have all the dependencies needed)

```
require __DIR__.'/../libraries/Silex/Provider/FormServiceProvider.php';
$app->register(
     new libraries\Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider(),
     array('form.class_path' => __DIR__ . '/../libraries',
));
```

When I add that code to register FormServiceProvider, every pages of my website turn blank and nothing is loaded but the bootstrap before this line.

After some testing, I found that the error is in this line

```
new libraries\Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider()
```

(Just doing a print_r(new libraries\Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider()) does the same error).

But nothing appears in the console (**EDIT :** Browser console) and I don't know what's wrong. I tryed modifying my error level to see if something appeared, but nothing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't get any error, only a blank page, no php loaded, no javascript and nothing in DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activate error log putting this in your bootstrap :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
```

Smells like a "class not found".

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me and displayed Class not found. Problem solved, the chosen directory was wrong.